# regex match blank or spaces javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm looking for a regex pattern that matches the following values:

- an empty string, or
- a string that contains only spaces.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use this regex:

```
/^\s*$/

Start of string 
Followed by zero or more whitespace 
End of string
```

Comment: +1 for being faster (*accursed minimum-character count hold-up..!*), *and* explaining.